# In Android Studio 3.0 i want to see layout preview design on device but unfortunately it is not showing.Please help me

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

[Here is the screenshot of that screen,after installing Android Studio 3.0 i face this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LorIq.png)

Comment: To clean out the android studio caches:

On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart. hope it help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the theme selector in the preview window ("MaterialTheme") and select an AppCompat one (or make your theme have that as parent).

The support components won't get rendered unless you select an AppCompat theme. I guess the MaterialTheme is your custom one, so just make sure it uses the appropriate theme as parent.

Comment: Please tell me the proper way how to do it.

Comment: After i select AppTheme now layout is showing.Thanks for the help.